# Fasterxml Jackson mapping - Data is not binding properly

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, fasterxml

I am trying to display my JSON in browser, I am getting data in JSON but getting only the last record of my table. Following jars are present in my build path,

- jackson-databind
- jackson-core
- jackson-annotations

Here is my controller method

```
  @RequestMapping("/viewDashboard")
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelMap test(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, @RequestParam String name) {

        ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
        List<Instances> instances = viewDashboardServiceImpl.viewDashboard();
        log.info(instances.size());
        return modelMap.addAllAttributes(instances);

    }
}
```

Actually in Database table i am five records, but in json I am getting only one record data.

In above method before adding instances list into modelMap object i am checking the size of the list and it is giving as five but in my JSON its showing only one record's data.

Here is my console output

**17:08:08,638 INFO  [com.mac.controller.DashboardController] (http--127.0.0.1-808
0-1) Size of Instances list: 5**

Here is my JSON

```
{"instances":{"id":5,"instanceName":".net","applications":{"id":3,"name":">net","ownerName":"Mou","version":"3kmnc"},"environments":{"id":2,"name":"IST","ownerName":"Mou","version":"1.23.asd"},"version":"2.3as"}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the real problem here is the `modelMap.addAllAttributes(instances)` call. *Spring*  will generate the keys for your list elements based on each element's classname.

For example:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("x", "y", "z");

ModelMap m = new ModelMap();
m.addAllAttributes(list);
```

Here the `ModelMap` will contain one entry with an attribute name `"string"` and a value `"z"`. `"x"` and `"y"` will not be in the map because every generated attribute name will be `"string"`, and the last one wins.

To fix this, simply assign an attribute name to your `instances` collection when adding them to the `modelMap`:

```
modelMap.addAttribute("myInstances", instances);
```